# Pandas: complex mapping between different sized DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two completely different dataframes that I need to map (thanks biology). All the tutorials out there on pandas are on much simpler conversions, and I can't get around solving this (real newbie) without 4 nested loops without success. Really curious on a pythonic way to solve this problem without having to go back to Excel.

The first is something like this df1. Observations of zeros and 1s for thousands of genes in a-j categories.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size =(10,10)),columns=list('abcdefghij'), index = ['gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene5','gene6','gene7','gene8','gene9','gene10'])

print(df1)

        a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
gene1   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
gene2   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
gene3   0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
gene4   1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1
gene5   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
gene6   0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
gene7   1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
gene8   0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0
gene9   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
gene10  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
```

Then the second is something like this df2. A mapping of higher level categories (X-W) for the lower level ones. This girl has NaNs and no indexes.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
                       'Y': ['d', 'b', 'c','f'],
                       'Z':['g', 'h','e','NaN'],
                       'W': ['i', 'j','NaN','Nan']},index=None)

print(df2)

     W    X  Y    Z
0    i    a  d    g
1    j  NaN  b    h
2  NaN  NaN  c    e
3  Nan  NaN  f  NaN
```

What I need is something like result1. Here resides another tricky thing. E.g. gene4 is in i and j categories, and both are in W, but I still just want a '1' in result1.loc['gene4','W']. The final result still needs to be binary.

```
result1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','1','1'],
                   'Y': ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','0'],
                   'Z': ['1','0','1','1','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
                   'W': ['1','1','0','1','0','1','1','1','1','1']}, index = ['gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene5','gene6','gene7','gene8','gene9','gene10'])
print(result1)


        W  X  Y  Z
gene1   1  1  1  1
gene2   1  0  1  0
gene3   0  0  1  1
gene4   1  1  1  1
gene5   0  0  1  0
gene6   1  0  1  1
gene7   1  1  1  1
gene8   1  0  1  1
gene9   1  1  1  1
gene10  1  1  0  1
```

This could be another possible result format. [updated with actual expected result]. If someone is feeling like teaching them both (or an easy interconversion), much extra appreciation, and science is also grateful.

```
result1 = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['gene1','gene1','gene1','gene1'],
                       '2': ['gene2','gene4','gene2','gene3'],
                       '3': ['gene4','gene7','gene3','gene4'],
                       '4': ['gene6','gene9','gene4','gene6'],
                       '5': ['gene7','gene10','gene5','gene7'],
                       '6': ['gene8','NaN','gene6','gene8'],
                       '7': ['gene9','NaN','gene7','gene9'],
                       '8': ['gene10','NaN','gene8','gene10'],
                       '9': ['NaN','NaN','gene9','NaN'],
                       },
                       index = ['W','X','Y','Z'])
print(result1)

       1      2      3      4       5      6      7       8      9
W  gene1  gene2  gene4  gene6   gene7  gene8  gene9  gene10    NaN
X  gene1  gene4  gene7  gene9  gene10    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN
Y  gene1  gene2  gene3  gene4   gene5  gene6  gene7   gene8  gene9
Z  gene1  gene3  gene4  gene6   gene7  gene8  gene9  gene10    NaN
```

Thank you a lot for your patience reading this long question.

Comment: What *exactly* is the relationship here? You provide a bunch of question marks and a random data... if you are going to go to all the trouble of creating these examples (very good for a first question!) just go the rest of the way and create the data-frame you want.

Comment: you are right, apologies. it wasn't that hard to add the question mark arrays, I just created one and copied it 4 times. I will solve for the toy example and edit the expected result dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go!  Let's try this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size =(10,10)),columns=list('abcdefghij'), index = ['gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene5','gene6','gene7','gene8','gene9','gene10'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
                       'Y': ['d', 'b', 'c','f'],
                       'Z':['g', 'h','e','NaN'],
                       'W': ['i', 'j','NaN','NaN']},index=None)

df2 = df2.replace('NaN',np.nan)

gmap = df2.stack().reset_index().drop('level_0',axis=1).set_index(0)['level_1']

df3 = df1.stack().replace(0,np.nan).dropna().reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].map(gmap).reset_index().drop_duplicates()

df_out = df3.groupby(['index','level_1'])['level_1'].count().unstack()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
level_1    W    X    Y    Z
index                      
gene1    1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
gene10   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
gene2    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
gene3    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
gene4    1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
gene5    1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
gene6    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
gene7    NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
gene8    NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
gene9    1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

## Edit to get optional output

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size =(10,10)),columns=list('abcdefghij'), index = ['gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene5','gene6','gene7','gene8','gene9','gene10'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
                       'Y': ['d', 'b', 'c','f'],
                       'Z':['g', 'h','e','NaN'],
                       'W': ['i', 'j','NaN','NaN']},index=None)

df2 = df2.replace('NaN',np.nan)

gmap = df2.stack().reset_index().drop('level_0',axis=1).set_index(0)['level_1']

df3 = df1.stack().replace(0,np.nan).dropna().reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].map(gmap).reset_index().drop_duplicates()

df3['cols'] = df3['index'].str.split('gene').str[1].astype(int)

df_out2 = df3.set_index(['level_1','cols'])['index'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
cols        1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9       10
level_1                                                                       
W        gene1  gene2  gene3  gene4  gene5   None  gene7  gene8  gene9  gene10
X         None   None  gene3   None  gene5   None   None  gene8  gene9  gene10
Y        gene1  gene2  gene3  gene4  gene5  gene6  gene7  gene8  gene9  gene10
Z         None  gene2   None  gene4   None  gene6   None  gene8  gene9    None
```

Comment: Amazing! Python is indeed magic. Minor detail, instead of NaNs I wanted zeros in the final result, but of course that can be quickly done with df_out.fillna(0). Thank you!

Comment: @JRCX I editted to solution get get optional output also.